How should I calculate the principal part of $ f(z) = \frac{\frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{\pi^2}}{e^z - e^{-z}}$ at the origin?
I want to calculate the principal part of the Laurent series of
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(z\right) =
\frac{1/z^{2} + 1/\pi^{2}}{{\rm e}^{z} - {\rm e}^{-z}}
$$
in a punctured neighbourhood of the origin.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this. I've tried to factorize the denominator:
$$
-{\rm e}^{-z}\left(1 - {\rm e}^{2z}\right)
$$
The right factor can be rewritten by using the formula for the geometric series:
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{2kz}
$$
So I get $-{\rm e}^{z} \left(1/z^{2} + 1|\pi^{2}\right)$
multiplied with the mentioned series.
What to do from here is unclear. Maybe I have to go back to the beginning and try a different approach ?

Does principal part mean the coefficient of $z^n$ for $n<0$?

The principal part is the sum of all the terms a×z^n for which the exponent n is negative.

Use the series for e^z and e^(-z)

How should I use those two series? I've tried that approach but don't get anywhere.

Expansion of hyperbolic functions.

The expansion of the hyperbolic cosecant function is given by
$$\begin{align}
\text{csch}(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2-2^{2n})B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}\\\\
&=\frac1z-\frac16 z+O(z^3)
\end{align}$$
where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers.
Therefore, the principal part of the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1/z^2-1/\pi^2}{e^2-e^{-z}}$ is
$$\text{P}f(z)= \frac1{2z^3}-\left(\frac1{12}+\frac1{2\pi^2}\right)\frac1{z}$$


If one is unfamiliar with the expansion of $\text{csch}(z)$, then one can proceed as follows.  The Taylor expansion of the complex expoential function is
$$\begin{align}
e^{z}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{align}$$
Hence, we see that
$$e^z-e^{-z}=2z+\frac{z^3}{3}+O(z^5)$$
Then, taking the reciprocal yields
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{e^z-e^{-z}}&=\frac1{2z+z^3/3+O(z^5)}\\\\
&=\frac1{2z}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+O(z^4)\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{2z}-\frac{z}{12}+O(z^3)
\end{align}$$
And proceed as in the previous development.

Nice calculation! Does "O(z^5)" mean a power series in z where all the exponents are greater than or equal to 5? How did you find the reciprocal?

The notation $O(z^5)$ is defined HERE.  As for the reciprocal of $1+x$ it is $1-x-x^2-\dots=1-x+O(x^2)$.  So, $\frac1{1+z^2/6+O(z^4)}=1-z^2/6+O(z^4)$.

Isn't 1/(1+x) = 1/(1-(-x)) = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - ... ?

@AA Indeed.  Apology for the typographical error.

No problem! Another thing: When you are talking about "the expansion of the hyperbolic cosecant function", do you then mean the Laurent series of that function in a punctured neighbourhood of the origin? If so, in what annulus does that series converge? Does it converge to the function?

@AA Yes.  The Laurent series.  It converges on $0<|z|<\pi$ since $B_{2n}$ is asymptotic to $(-1)^{n+1} 4\sqrt{4n}(n/\pi e)^{2n}$.
